# How to change response to Windows Security Alert in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet-security, security-warning

I accidentally selected the public networks option on the Windows Security Alert shown below but for a different application which should not be communicating on a public network!

[image: shown here]

Where can I change these settings?

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel -> Windows Firewall -> "Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall" in the left panel.